# Conditional WHERE in SQL query based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table

| Id | UserId | IsPrivate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 21 | true | Done |
| 11 | 21 | true | Doing |
| 12 | 21 | false | Doing |
| 13 | 21 | false | Doing |
| 14 | 20 | false | Doing |

I would like to filter by UserId.

Then comes the hard part.

For the rows **where IsPrivate is true**, I would like to show only the ones **where Status is Done**

This should be the result for UserId = 21

| Id | UserId | IsPrivate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 21 | true | Done |
| 12 | 21 | false | Doing |
| 13 | 21 | false | Doing |

The row with ID 11 does not show because IsPrivate is *true* and Status is *Doing*

How can I write this query?

I hope you have an awesome day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE UserId = ? 
AND ((IsPrivate = true and Status = "Done") OR IsPrivate = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean logic can be a mind bender :) If in doubt, perhaps spelling out a complete [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) can help?

One way to approach your query would be this:

```sql
-- If IsPrivate is a boolean
WHERE NOT IsPrivate OR Status = 'Done'

-- If IsPrivate is a string
WHERE IsPrivate != 'true' OR Status = 'Done'
```

Comment: It shows only rows that IsPrivate is false.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually answered your question already in your question.

You explained

> The row with ID 11 does not show because IsPrivate is true and Status is Doing

Therefore, you want exactly the opposite of that condition so that's what you need to write

```
select * 
from t
where userid=21 and not (IsPrivate='true' and Status='Doing')
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to improve my original answer. So if I understand this right, you want to apply some conditional logic on Status field within the select clause, which may result in something like this:

```sql
select t.Id, t.UserId, t.IsPrivate
, case when t.IsPrivate = 'true' and t.Status = 'Done' then t.Status else NULL end status
from table t
where t.UserId = 21
```

Comment: Hi, pnowk! It is not what I intended to do.

Comment: Hi, @leotuna. I might have misunderstood your intention. I have edited the original answer, so see if it's more like what you're looking for.